# Backbone render View not displayed...only in console

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I have my backbone router:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes:{
        "" : "productos",
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.productoItem = new Producto();
        //Crear la vista del detalle de un producto

        this.productoItems = new Productos();
        this.productoItems.fetch();

        this.productosView = new ProductsView({collection: this.productoItems});
    },

    productos: function(){
        $('#app').html(this.productosView.render().el);
      //this line seems not to working but putting in a console does the work
    }

});

/*********************************/
var app = new AppRouter();

$(function(){
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Heres the view:

```
var ProductsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(Handlebars.templates.products(this.collection));
        return this;
    }
});
```

And finally my handlebar template:

```
<h1>Y LOS MODELOS SON</h1>
<ul>
{{#each models}}
<li>
{{attributes.familia}}
</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

So when i run this app it only renders the  Y LOS MODELOS SON that means that 
`$('#app').html(this.productosView.render().el)`; works but no completely only the html tags...but when i do this:

```
$('#app').html(app.productosView.render().el)
```

in the console it works perfectly...
Can someone explains me what am i missing??
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Collection#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) is an AJAX call so `AppRouter#productos` is being called before the server has sent anything back. The result is that the collection is empty when `ProductsView#render` is called and `{{#each models}}` in your template has nothing to iterate over.

`Collection#fetch` uses [`Collection#set`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set) to merge the fetched models into the collection. That will trigger `"add"`, `"remove"`, and `"change"` events on the collection. You can listen for those events from the collection and re-render:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add remove change', this.render);
}
```

but that will be pretty wasteful as you'll re-render the view for each newly added model. An alternative is to fetch with `{reset:true}`:

> When the model data returns from the server, it uses *set* to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass `{reset: true}`, in which case the collection will be (efficiently) *reset*.

and [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) will trigger a single `"reset"` event. So in your router, you could say:

```
this.productoItems = new Productos();
this.productoItems.fetch({ reset: true });
```

and then in your view:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
}
```

Using `{reset: true}` seems like the easiest thing to use in your case.